# Freewheel in vinegar

Tags: shimano, freewheel, rust

I'm renovating an older bike. I took the 6 speed freewheel (Shimano mf-tz20) off because it was rusty, disassembled, chucked the parts in vinegar overnight. The rust came off, but so did the goldish tint of the cogs. I'm assuming the steel cogs had some coating applied to them to prevent rust/harden, I'm not exactly sure. My question is, what kind of coating did I strip off the freewheel, and what can I do to prevent rust on the now bare steel surface?

[image: shimano mf tz20]

Comment: Just use it till it does.  Chain lube and WD40.

Comment: If you take a look at images of the specified model, you'll see the cogs have this gold-ish factory tint.

Comment: If you're really worried about this, I'd just spend the 8-10 bucks on a replacement freewheel. I'm with @Paparazzi on this, sans the WD40.

Comment: My guess is that moreso the grease and what not in the bearings of the freewheel may have degraded from this vinegar soak, unless for some reason you fully tore down the freewheel and repacked it (which is likely more expense/work than just getting the replacement).

Comment: You can buy 20 of these freewheels for about 1 high spec ultegra cassette.  Sometimes its worth replacing wear parts with new ones.  Chains and freewheels are not worth the time to salvage.

Comment: My old bike with a cheap steel freewheel lives outside and the gears get spayed with GT85 every now and then. This keeps them almost rust free.

Comment: If you lube your chain regularly, enough lube will rub off on the freewheel to keep it clear of corrosion, unless you consistently leave it out in the rain.

Answer (score 5):

Baked on grease can look yellow or the manufacturer might have coated it with something. In this case, it looks like the manufacturer gave it a light coating.

Normally the lube from your chain (especially if you use a tacky lube) is enough to prevent corrosion. But if you're worried, why not just give it an extra coating of silicone oil.

For bare metal parts, I also use [Boeshield](https://boeshield.com/), figuring if it's good enough for BOEing to SHIELD aeronautical parts from corrosion, it's good enough for my bike. I use it on places like hex bolt heads which seem to attract corrosion but you could also use inside your cassette.

<sub>Fineprints: But (along the lines of what  @Criggie points out) it might be cheaper to buy a new freewheel than a can of Boeshield... Another side note is that using an acid to strip rust can be a bad idea because it leaves the exposed metal in a particularly vulnerable state for corrosion. Because rust on the sides of the sprockets really doesn't hurt you, I would have just degreased with a citrus degreaser and left the rust alone -- or bought a new freewheel.</sub>